# Paramiko stdout.read gives "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'"

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm new to Python so apologies if I missed something.

I'm creating a script that can connect to Linux machines to run a couple commands and output those results to be used in an HTML report. When I run the script (minus the HTML report generation) it is throwing the following error, when the commands are passed over to the function that executes the CLI command:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

How do I handle this type of error in the function when there will be about 30 different CLI commands passed to it and need to return the results?

```
import paramiko as paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient

# Connect

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('', username='', password='', look_for_keys=False)

def ExecSSHCommand(cli):
    stdout = ssh.exec_command(cli)

    print(type(stdout))  # <class 'paramiko.channel.ChannelFile'>

    # Print output of command. Will wait for command to finish.
    print(f'STDOUT: {stdout.read().decode("utf8")}')

    stdout.close()

    # Close the client itself
    ssh.close()

status = ExecSSHCommand('show status') 
service = ExecSSHCommand('show services')
```

This is the full error:

```
line 55, in <module>
  status = ExecSSHCommand('show status') line 22,
in ExecSSHCommand print(f'STDOUT: {stdout.read().decode("utf8")}')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec_command` indeed returns a stdin/stdout/stderr tuple.

You want this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cli)
```

---

*Another unrelated thing is that you cannot close the `SSHClient` after the each command. So this has to be moved from the end of the `ExecSSHCommand` function to to the end of the script:*

```
ssh.close()
```